# GE timer switch (no neutral) to connect to a bathroom fan/light

Tags: electrical, wiring

I previously had this working, but it stopped working so I replaced the fan unit (it was old and starting to make noise) with a new one. I'm trying to retrace the wiring to make sure I have it all correctly wired, which is a bit trickier given that several pieces of my older house's wiring aren't using the standard color schemes. I am in the USA

Essentially I have a GE countdown timer switch that requires no neutral (this one [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007BJULYS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007BJULYS))
that has the wiring diagram shown as below in (1).

Coming from there into the fan receptacle unit via the attic, I have 3 cables - a black, a white and a green/ground wire.

Then have this fan/light, has two outlets that the components (fan, light) plug into. Both have a white wire, one has a blue, one has a black - so a total of those 4 wires for the light/fan combo.

I've included a picture of my wall receptacle w/ the switch, as well as the fan. I thought this may have been correct and the same as how I had it connected originally (sans the temporary snap connectors), but while the switch lights up to show it has power and I can hear it "click" to activate when pushed, I don't seem to get power on the other side. Non-contact tool senses current after clicking on both the black and red coming out of switch, but nothing on the other end. I have the fan and light component plugged in, with a bulb in the light.

Thoughts? Anything I should try differently? More info I can provide to help? Thanks!

1. [image: Switch wiring diagram]

[Links to additional photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROcLs.jpg) - more photos here of wiring!

Comment: This may seam like a silly question but are you sure your black is hot? In the past I have run switch legs down from the attic the white is the hot it should be remarked, then I can control a fan and a light with the black and red, very inexpensive way to have multiple devices in a bathroom.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I verified that the black was hot using voltmeter. There are more photos in the "Links to additional photos" link that show the inside of the box. After about 5 more hours, I actually found (part of) the culprit. From the switch box, the wire goes to a small junction box in the attic, where it connected to two other "outputs" - one was romex to the fan/light receptacle, the other was to some other unknown item that must have failed far near the side of the roof line - I didn't notice anything else on the circuit, likely some legacy vestige. Bypassed and now it fan/light works